# Dataloader caches across context creations (graphQl ApolloServer)

Tags: node.js, express, apollo, apollo-server, dataloader

I have integrated DataLoaders into my graphQL requests, but for some reason the cache is memoized across requests. I can read that passing a function to context in the ApolloServer config should create a new context on each request, but for some reason the DataLoaders are memoized even then.

This is my code

Apollo Config:

```
export default new ApolloServer({
  resolvers,
  typeDefs,
  context: ({ req, res }) => generateContext(req, res)
});
```

generateContext:

```
const generateContext = (req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response) => ({
  ...generateLoaders(),
  res,
  req
});
```

generateLoaders:

```
import * as questionLoaders from './questionLoaders';

const generateLoaders = () => ({
  questionLoaders
});
```

questionLoader:

```
const batchQuestions = async (ids: number[]) => {
  const questions = await Question.query().findByIds(ids);
  return ids.map((id) => questions.find((q) => q.id === id));
};

export const questionLoader = new dataloader((ids: number[]) => batchQuestions(ids));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only call the `DataLoader` constructor once and then export the resulting DataLoader instance as a constant. Even though your context function is called on each request, it uses the imported value, which is always the same DataLoader instance. Change your export so that it is a function:

```
export const createQuestionLoader = () => new dataloader((ids: number[]) => batchQuestions(ids));
```

You can then import it and call the function inside `context`:

```
import { createQuestionLoader } from '...'

const generateContext = (req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response) => ({
  QuestionLoader: createQuestionLoader(),
  res,
  req
});
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Is it possible to refactor the QuestionLoader into generateLoaders without losing the new instance on each context? I have several other loaders that are not shown, and the context file would eventually get very big.

Comment: Yes, the main point is to export a function that creates a loader instance instead of exporting a loader instance itself. If you want to call that function inside another function like `generateLoaders`, that's fine.

Comment: This is causing me issues on my production server, but works locally. On production the dataloader doesn't seem to initialize (or inititalize in time)

Comment: @A.com please open a new issue with a complete code example.

Comment: @DanielRearden completely was my fault... I had weird logic around my context object on a graphql server